# How to set different Layouts in Croogo

Tags: croogo

I try to use different layout for different pages in croogo, But I have a problem. For example. I want to have 2 layouts: default and my_custome. default is for page1, my_custome is for Page2. How to achieve this ?   Is any Plugins available ? please do help me if you know the solutions.?

Answer (score 0):

Croogo has fallbacks for its Nodes: http://wiki.croogo.org/1.3/designers/themes/fallback-system

From the custom view file, you can try setting `$this->layout = 'whatever';`.